# How to create 2 related dropdownlists

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, html, jquery

I have mvc3 (with C#) application about phone accessories. There is Accessory model that it has Tag property. When I create new Accessory object, I give some values to its Tag property as Nokia, Samsung, E55, C15, Blackberry etc. I will use Tag property in accessories searching.
In search time, I want user select phone name from dropdownlist, then in other dropdownlist that phones models dynamically are loading. For examlpe, when I select Nokia, in bottom dropdownlist Nokia's models are loading as N8, E51, E55, etc..

How can I determine Phone name and its models lists and bind those dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Comment: Please add a brief text on what your linked page contains. Although unlikely, in case your link goes bad, at least people will still have an idea what it used to have.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Ajax.BeginForm` with a Partial View to replace the contents of the 2nd drop down. You can use Javascript to use the 1st drop down list's `onchange` event to post back the Ajax form.

Make sure you also include:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

for Ajax to work with MVC3 asuming you're using unobtrusive javascript default config settings.